# Smooth shading and colored shadows

Tags: shaders

When I set the shading of a mesh to smooth, the shadows on the mesh are always black when rendered, but I need them to be blue. When I set the shading to flat the color of the shading turns out fine. Is there a way to make smooth shading not black?[image]

The person is set on flat and the scarf is smooth. I'm using Blender Internal.

Comment: Blender Internal or Cycles? Also, what version?

Comment: can you post pictures that show the issue?

Comment: Colored shadows can be accomplished by adding a light with the color facing toward the shadowy area http://i.stack.imgur.com/igJbl.png

Answer (score 1):

I think the most easy method is to set Ambient Color in the World tab.
[image]